# SSL Authentication for secured services

Tags: ssl, microservices

I have two applications first is TestA and second is TestB,
TestB application is secured "https" with SSL certificate.

I need to use web services of application TestB from TestA.

- How I can pass anything for SSL authentication from application TestA.
- Is there is any parameter, Argument, or Key that we need to pass while calling web services form Test A ?

Comment: HTTPS just ensure that connection between you and the server is trustworthy, in this case form TestA to testB. Its upto testA to decide if it wants to talk to some one who is over https or not. If it wants to, testA can check the SSL certificate, see who signed it and for whom its signed and then can proceed further. **Are you getting any error** when trying to connect, if you are getting ssl error, you just need to add the certificates for the ssl provider in your keystore. Or you can ignore the ssl error as well (if you want to)